# Scrolling whole screen and not just tableview

Tags: swift, scroll, tableview

Sorry if this is a basic question. I have a UIViewController with a Tableview starting at the middle of my screen. I can get my tableview to scroll, but I would like to be able to scroll the whole screen and not just starting from the tableview. Right now, when I scroll, the top half of the screen stays fixed and only the tableview scrolls, but I would like to start scrolling the whole screen.

Comment: Hey - I need some clarification with your question. Is your tableview ever going to scroll? Do you want it to be scroll locked and only have the screen be able to scroll? I can help you if you clarify those details!

Comment: Whatever you want to scroll apart from tableView put that content in tableViewHeader or tableViewFooter.

Comment: @cloudcal I would like the tableview data to scroll, but since the tableview starts in the middle of the screen, I would like to be able to scroll the entire screen and not just from where the tableview starts

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

select your **table view** in the storyboard and turn off **scrolling enabled** (under the scroll view section in attributes inspector).

Alternatively, put this in your TableViewController viewDidLoad:

```
tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the kind of effect you want, but you can work with the content inset of the tableView like that:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController : UIViewController {


    let tableView: UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView()
        tv.backgroundColor = .green
        return tv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Scrolling"

        view.backgroundColor = .blue



        view.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.frame = view.frame

        let SCREENH = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: SCREENH/2, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }

}
```

or if you have have content on top of the tableView and doesn't want the effect given by the contentInset method, why not implementing a header for your tableView and putting your info in there.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is select the TableView in Storyboard and then click on attributes.There you will find the checkbox "Scrolling Enabled" just uncheck the checkbox and then the scrolling of tableview is disabled.

I can you help you more if you clarify me which container(either scrollView or anything else you used as a SuperView)